# Can I turn these two almost identical functions into one in python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have these two functions which are nearly identical apart from the if statement in search_genre, is there any way to combine them into one?

The books variable is a dictionary where each value is a list of dictionaries, i.e.:

books = {'Genre1':[{name:value, author:value}, {dict}], 'Genre2':[{dict}], and so on}

view_library() prints all the books and 
search_genre() takes a user input to print all books of a specific genre

```
def view_library():
    for genre in books:
        print(f'Genre: {genre}')
        for book in books[genre]:
            for key, value in book.items():
                print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
            print()


def search_genre(genre_type):
    for genre in books:
        if genre_type == genre:
            print(f'{genre_type}:')
            for book in books[genre_type]:
                for key, value in book.items():
                    print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
                print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def search_genre(genre_type=None):
    for genre in books:
        if genre_type is None or genre_type == genre:
            print(f'{genre_type}:')
            for book in books[genre_type]:
                for key, value in book.items():
                    print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
                print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the 2 functions is that in the first, all genres are processed, while in the second only the chosen on is.

The key is the `if` statement that determines whether the genre is printed: right now, it only fires if the genre matches the provided genre. We can add an `or` so that it *also* fires if no genre_type is provided. Now, if we call the function without a `genre_type` argument, it will print all genres:

```
def search_genre(genre_type=None):
    for genre in books:
        if not genre_type or genre_type == genre:
            print(f'{genre_type}:')
            for book in books[genre_type]:
                for key, value in book.items():
                    print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
                print()
```

Since you don't provide a MCVE of data, here's a simplified example with data to show how it works:

```
def test(x=None):
    for y in z:
        if not x or x == y:
            print(y)

z = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

test()
1
2
3
4
5
6

test(5)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by implementing `filter_by_genre` using a filter. It's basically the same as `search_genre`.

```
def filter_by_genre(genre_type):
    for genre in filter(lambda x: x == genre_type, books):
        print(f'{genre_type}:')
        for book in books[genre]:
            for key, value in book.items():
                print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
            print()

filter_by_genre("mystery")
```

Now, instead of passing a genre as an argument, pass a predicate:

```
def filter_by_genre(p):
    for genre in filter(p, books):
        print(f'{genre_type}:')
        for book in books[genre]:
            for key, value in book.items():
                print(f"{key.title()} : {value.title()}")
            print()

filter_by_genre(lambda x: x == "mystery")
```

Both `view_library` and `search_genre` can then be implemented in terms of `filter_by_genre`:

```
def view_library():
    return filter_by_genre(lambda x: True)


def search_genre(genre_type):
    return filter_by_genre(lambda x: x == genre_type)
```